# Is there a way to repopulate with command-line a postgres db that I can't drop?

Tags: postgresql, command-line, docker, database-backups

I'm looking to load a database from a backup.gz. The backup is raw sql generated from  `pg_dump -U postgres app_development -f backup.gz -Z9`.

I've tried dropping the db with `psql -Upostgres -c "drop database app_development"` but I get:

```
ERROR:  database "app_development" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There are 3 other sessions using the database.
```

The same thing happens when I use `dropdb`.

I don't want to dump to a non-ascii version so I don't think I can use pg_restore.

Also, I'm not sure if it helps, but all this is happening in docker.

Comment: Currently, I am just restarting the docker container, dropping the db, and then creating it and loading the dump.  This has a lot more steps in it than I want though.

Comment: Why don't you just kill those connections that are using the database?

Comment: When I kill them they don't come back again. Right now I'm just rebooting the container which drops the connections, making the changes and then rebooting all of the dependant containers. Which works, but is a lot more overhead that I was hoping for.

Comment: So how do you kill them? `pg_cancel_backend()` or `pg_terminate_backend()`?

Comment: Nice, pg_cancel_backend wasn't working but pg_terminate_backend does.  Thanks a bunch. It also, doesn't disconnect my other containers.

Comment: `pg_cancel_backend()` is more like a polite question to the backend to end after the current statement/transaction has finished. `pg_terminate_backend()` is a brute force kill command.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name if you want to put your comment as an answer I'll accept it as correct